# How do I prevent ASP.NET MVC from binding query parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I think this is similar to [How to disable binding of the route values in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314359/how-to-disable-binding-of-the-route-values-in-asp-net-mvc), but I didn't understand that answer.

I have a proxy action in one of my controllers that looks something like this

```
public ActionResult Proxy(string path) {
    // Issue a request to another server for the provided path
}
```

and a route rule like this

```
routes.MapRoute("Proxy", "Proxy/{*path}", new { controller = "Proxy", action = "Proxy" });
```

This allows me to proxy requests like http://www.website.com/Proxy/some/path/here to http://api.someotherwebsite.com/some/path/here and this works fine. However, if I have query parameters, e.g. http://www.website.com/Proxy/some/path/here?x=1234, MVC tries to bind the query parameter `x` to the Proxy action, so the `path` parameter ends up getting the value `some/path/here` instead of `some/path/here?x=1234`. How can I prevent this behavior and have the query parameters included in the path parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly instead of trying to mess with custom routing it seems far easier in your case to just appended the query string back to your path parameter.

`OtherServerRequest(path + "?" + Request.QueryString);`

Comment: I'm dumb - that was easy